# onEdit has a long 2+ seconds Delay. Is this script correct and is there a way to optimize it?

Tags: javascript, excel

This is the current code I'm using to move cells from one sheet to another, but there is a long delay and sometimes it does not function on execution.  Does this code look correct and is there anyway to optimize it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bxnr.png)

Comment: It's best to copy/paste the code here for us to review rather than a link to an external image

Comment: And include the code that calls the onEdit function